# Jira-Hudson-Mercurial integration

Tags: mercurial, hudson, jira

When a developer commits a bugfix, I want to be able to open up the relevant JIRA issue and see what Hudson build number contains this fix with the Mercurial changeset listed alongside.

Extra points if this information is listed in its own tab (does not pollute the "comments" tab) but shows up alongside comments when the "all" tab is selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the Marvelution plugin is supposed to resolve this problem: http://issues.marvelution.com/browse/MARVJIRAHUDSON-94

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [jira plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JIRA+Plugin) for Hudson. It is a simple plugin, that I think should be pretty sufficient for the most use cases.

On the plugin page another project is referenced. The marvelution Jira Hudson Integration project. It comes with two plugins, one for jira and one for Hudson and if the app lives up the promise, it will be an pretty cool tool. I found two different locations to read about it because they are in the process of moving their site to a wiki; [old location](http://www.marvelution.com/atlassian/jira-hudson-integration/) and [new location](http://docs.marvelution.com/display/MARVJIRAHUDSON/Documentation+Home).

Comment: For Mercurial and Jira you have to google yourself. I found on a quick search following plugin. https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/4994

Comment: Yup, I wrote that JIRA Mercurial plugin based on the JIRA Subversion plugin. I thought the existing JIRA Hudson plugin showed builds as a tab on the issue, next to the Mercurial tab? It would be cool if the two played nicely together.

Comment: The JIRA plugin pollutes the comments tab. The Marvelution plugin does not show up in the "all" tab. Neither one makes it easy to associate a build with a Mercurial changeset.